# Rails: What the best way to check empty of integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is:

```
"1".empty? == false
```

But:

```
1.empty? == NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 1:Fixnum
```

If I change it to `blank?`

```
"1".blank? == false

1.blank? == false
```

So, I want to know the other way to check an integer is empty or not because I hate `blank?`

Comment: Why do you hate `blank?` ? It's exactly what you need.

Comment: what does "integer is empty or not" mean?

Comment: sorry, @KoichiroWada i mean if `n = 1 and return if n.empty?` something like that

Comment: @ZedTuX Thanks, may be i'm bad

Comment: @mant1988 so why did you accept the answer? And I'm still interested to know why you hate `blank?`, so if you can share your arguments that would be good in order to make me understand your point of view :)

Comment: @ZedTuX i accepted the answer below in same day as i asked questions, did u see? and i hate blank? becasue i want to know the best way to check it, if the best answer is blank?, i pleasure to accepted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some examples about nil? and empty?

```rb
nil.nil?
# => true

false.nil?
# => false

1.nil?
# => false

0.nil?
# => false

"".nil?
# => false

[].nil?
# => false

"".empty?
# => true

"abc".empty?
# => false

[].empty?
# => true

[1, 2, 3].empty?
=> false

1.empty?
=> NoMethodError
```

The last example means that the `empty?` method is not defined for class 
Fixnum